# Assign value to model from Action Validation - Dot net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to assign a value to model before it hits a controller. E.g I have a userid fields on model where I need to assign it centrally that's why I have implemented Validation Filter in asp.net core.
This is how I have implemented

```
public class ActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private int branchId = 0;
    private int userId = 0;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result;

        if (result != null)
        {
            InternalDataViewModel model = new InternalDataViewModel();

            var viewResult = result as BaseViewModel;

            if (model != null)
            {
                model.BranchId = 10;
                model.UserId = 10;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Here I want to assign a value to that InternalDataViewModel class but this is not working as expected. How can I achieve this please help me out guys

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do such a thing ? There are other options, for example you could assign values in a ctor if the object

Comment: @Fabjan - I would get that user id from HttpContext so that I don't have to assign userid every time

Comment: And what exactly is not working as expected ?

Comment: Btw  `OnActionExecuted` is called *after* the action method which means it already 'hits' the controller. Try to move the code to `OnActionExecuting`